# save two images into two separate files using same python script

Tags: python

How to save two images into two separate files using same python script. The two output images are correlation matrix and a graph. I was using matplotlib

```
imshow(matrix, interpolation='bilinear')
colorbar()
savefig('/home/sudipta/Downloads/phppython/'+ filename +'.png')
x = range(-width, width)
plt.plot(x, avg_vec)
plt.savefig('/home/sudipta/'+ filename +'plot' +'.png')
```

The figures overlap each other when I run this script. However, I need two separate images. Initially, I was trying to save those images in same directory. I thought may be there is problem. Then I had tried to save in a different directory. However, I did not succedd

Comment: Can you clarify this question? What is the source of these images? What is the difficulty in saving them? Some code is likely to help here!

Comment: I can't figure out how to do it. Please help me in this regard

Answer (score 4):

I think you should add pyplot.clf() in between.

```
#plot your first image
pyplot.savefig('filename.ext') # ext is your chosen filetype. jpg, png, etc.

# clear the plot
pyplot.clf()

# plot your second image
pyplot.savefig('filename2.ext')
```

The function clf (clear figure) removes everything from the current axis you are drawing on.

Another option would be to create two different figure objects.

```
# create figures and axes
fig0 = pyplot.figure()
ax0 = fig0.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
fig1 = pyplot.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

# draw on ax0, e.g. with ax0.plot(...)
# draw on ax1

fig0.savefig('fig0.png')
fig1.savefig('fig1.png')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#plot your first image
pyplot.savefig('filename.ext') # ext is your chosen filetype. jpg, png, etc.

#plot your second image
pyplot.savefig('filename2.ext')
```